# Servlet arrayList returning null

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, http

the issue I seem to be facing is that my arrayList of objects keeps returning null and I;m unable to figure out why. My code is below:

```
   <% ArrayList<Product> pList = new ArrayList<>();
            pList = (ArrayList<Product>) session.getAttribute("productList");
            for (int i = 0; i < pList.size(); i++) {%>
        <tr>
            <td><%pList.get(i).getProductID();%></td>
            <td><%pList.get(i).getManufacturer();%></td>
            <td><%pList.get(i).getItem();%></td>
            <td><%pList.get(i).getDescription();%></td>
            <td><%pList.get(i).getPrice();%></td>
            <td>
                <form action=<%=response.encodeURL("AddtoCartServlet.do")%> method="POST">
                      Quantity:<input type="text" name="quantity">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
                    <%--<input type="hidden" name="prodID" value=<%=product.getProductID();%>--%>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

and the code for my servlet is here:

```
     @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    ProductDAO dao = new ProductDAO();
    ArrayList<Product> productList = dao.getAllProducts();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("productList", productList);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("productList.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

finally, the code to retrieve all product objects is here:

```
    public ArrayList<Product> getAllProducts() {
    ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList();

    Connection conn = DBConnector.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Product";
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Product prod = new Product();
            prod.setProductID(rs.getString("ProductId"));
            prod.setManufacturer(rs.getString("Manufacturer"));
            prod.setItem(rs.getString("Item"));
            prod.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));
            prod.setPrice(rs.getDouble("Price"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProductDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println(ex.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println(ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        DBConnector.closeJDBCObjects(null, stmt, rs);
    }
    return productList;
}
```

Comment: Does it mean your JSP fails on the `for (int i = 0; i < pList.size(); i++) {%>` line with NullPointerException? (Btw. the loop code itself is horrible, what about something like `for (Product prod : pList)` and then using `prod.getProductId()` in table cells. Not mentioning the JSTL `<c:forEach>` and EL...)

Comment: Yes, when debugging the project, the pList returns null meaning no product is filling the list

Comment: Well, there is no way (at least not in your code) `pList` itself could be `null`, but now I've just noticed, that in your `while (rs.next())` loop, a statement adding a newly created product into the list is missing, i.e. `productList.add(prod);` - which means the `pList` in your JSP is always empty (empty list **is not** null, neither it contains nulls).

Comment: I see. I've added productList.add(prod) to the loop however when trying to get to the JSP i still receive an error on line 36: for (int i = 0; i < pList.size(); i++) {%>

Comment: check whether the values are fully added to the arraylist from the servlet itself

Comment: Did you fix this problem? I wonder what is return from `dao.getAllProducts()`. Could you check this by print in console?